# PYTHONPATH -bash: export: `myproject/tornado_main.py': not a valid identifier

Tags: python, django, bash

I am trying to do learn from the django-tornado-demo at https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo . There is this executable that I need to run. The following is the code block:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Run this with
# PYTHONPATH=. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testsite.settings testsite/tornado_main.py
# Serves by default at
# http://localhost:8080/hello-tornado and
# http://localhost:8080/hello-django

from tornado.options import options, define, parse_command_line
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.wsgi

define('port', type=int, default=8080)

class HelloHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.write('Hello from tornado')

def main():
  parse_command_line()
  wsgi_app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer(
    django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler())
  tornado_app = tornado.web.Application(
    [
      ('/hello-tornado', HelloHandler),
      ('.*', tornado.web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=wsgi_app)),
      ])
  server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(tornado_app)
  server.listen(options.port)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

when I try to do the Python path export:

> export PYTHONPATH=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings
>   myproject/tornado_main.py

I get:

> -bash: export: `myproject/tornado_main.py': not a valid identifier

How do you run this file with PYTHONPATH that is suggested at the top? Thanks

Comment: You read the line listed at the top more carefully and do what it says not something you cobbled together from what you think it says. (i.e. That line is *verbatim* what you need.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `export`, just run it directly as written from the CLI:

```
PYTHONPATH=. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testsite.settings testsite/tornado_main.py
```

This will run `tornado_main.py` with the altered environment variables. You *could* do this, too:

```
export PYTHONPATH=. 
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testsite.settings 
testsite/tornado_main.py
```

If you want the changes to `PYTHONPATH` and `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to affect all processes you launch from that terminal.

**Edit:**

```
dan@dantop2:~/code/django-tornado-demo$ ls
testsite
dan@dantop2:~/code/django-tornado-demo$ ls testsite/
__init__.py  manage.py  settings.py  tornado_main.py  urls.py  views.py
dan@dantop2:~/code/django-tornado-demo$ PYTHONPATH=. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testsite.settings testsite/tornado_main.py
<server starts running>
```

Comment: @Eddie Are you running it from the directory above `testsite`? Is `tornado_main.py` executable?

Comment: tornado_main.py is the sample code I have included above in my question. It is an executable.

Comment: This is the repository I am looking at: https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo/blob/master/testsite/tornado_main.py

Comment: @Eddie when I `git clone` that repo, `cd` to `django-tornado-demo`, and run `PYTHONPATH=. DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testsite.settings testsite/tornado_main.py`, the server starts up, just like it should. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: My hitch I guess was that I am trying to integrate it with an app that  I just made. So I have to integrate my app. I will try your edit

Comment: I just tried it too and it works. Awesome! So I have a little fixing up to do.